# Bootstrap-Vue: Implementing Role Permissions as Multiple arrays of b-form-checkbox displayed as columns in b-table. Not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

**The Problem**
I am trying to create a page to manage permissions by role as demonstrated in the following image:

[image: No boxes checked yet...]

As currently implemented, a click in any box results in all of the boxes in that column becoming checked.

Ex.: a click in "Create Users" of "Admin" will look as follows:

[image: All of the boxes in Admin got checked!]

Likewise, a check in any of the other columns would result in all of the check boxes for that column being checked. In either case, clearing any checkbox also clears all the checkboxes in that column.

I'm not sure what's going on, but note that if I reverse the comments in the table and run with the other checkboxes, the behavior is such that all columns under "Admin" get checked regardless of which column I checked a box.

Here's the relevant template html and script for the component as well as a the relevant script from the vuex store. Thanks in advance for any help!!

```js
import {
  store
} from "../store/store";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: this.$store.state.permissions,
      roles: this.$store.state.roles,

      adminRolePermissions: this.$store.state.roles[this.$store.state.roles.map(function(permission) {
        return permission.name;
      }).indexOf('Admin')].rolePermissions,
      salesRolePermissions: this.$store.state.roles[this.$store.state.roles.map(function(permission) {
        return permission.name;
      }).indexOf('Sales')].rolePermissions,
      maintRolePermissions: this.$store.state.roles[this.$store.state.roles.map(function(permission) {
        return permission.name;
      }).indexOf('Maintenance')].rolePermissions,
      accouRolePermissions: this.$store.state.roles[this.$store.state.roles.map(function(permission) {
        return permission.name;
      }).indexOf('Accounting')].rolePermissions,

      fields: [{
          key: "name",
          label: "Permission",
          class: "text-right"
        },
        {
          key: "admin",
          label: "Admin",
          class: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "sales",
          label: "Sales",
          class: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "maint",
          label: "Maintenance",
          class: "text-center"
        },
        {
          key: "account",
          label: "Accounting",
          class: "text-center"
        },
      ]
    };
  },
```

```html
        <b-table responsive :items="items" :fields="fields" head-variant="dark">
            <template slot="admin" slot-scope="row">
              <b-form-checkbox id="admin" v-model="adminRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
              <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="adminRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/>               -->
            </template>
            <template slot="sales" slot-scope="row">
              <b-form-checkbox id="sales" v-model="salesRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
              <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="salesRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/>               -->
            </template>
            <template slot="maint" slot-scope="row">
              <b-form-checkbox id="maint" v-model="maintRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
              <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="salesRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/> -->              
            </template>            
            <template slot="account" slot-scope="row">
              <b-form-checkbox id="accou" v-model="accouRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>              
              <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="accouRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/> -->
            </template>
        </b-table>
```

**The store (vuex):**

```js
permissions: [{
      id: "u1",
      name: "View Users",
      grouping: "Users"
    },
    {
      id: "u2",
      name: "Create Users",
      grouping: "Users"
    },
    {
      id: "u3",
      name: "Remove Users",
      grouping: "Users"
    },
    {
      id: "u4",
      name: "Modify Users",
      grouping: "Users"
    },
    {
      id: "u5",
      name: "Assign Users To Roles",
      grouping: "Users"
    },
    {
      id: "r1",
      name: "Create Roles",
      grouping: "Roles"
    },
    {
      id: "r2",
      name: "Modify Roles",
      grouping: "Roles"
    },
    {
      id: "a1",
      name: "View Assets",
      grouping: "Assets"
    },
    {
      id: "a2",
      name: "Create Asset",
      grouping: "Assets"
    },
    {
      id: "a3",
      name: "Update Asset Info",
      grouping: "Assets"
    },
    {
      id: "a4",
      name: "Locate Assets",
      grouping: "Assets"
    },
    {
      id: "a5",
      name: "Change Asset Availability",
      grouping: "Assets"
    },
    {
      id: "m1",
      name: "View Asset Maintenance Records",
      grouping: "Maintenance"
    },
    {
      id: "m2",
      name: "Change Asset Maintenance Records",
      grouping: "Maintenance"
    },
    {
      id: "c1",
      name: "View Customer",
      grouping: "Customers"
    },
    {
      id: "c2",
      name: "Create Customer",
      grouping: "Customers"
    },
    {
      id: "c3",
      name: "Modify Customer Info",
      grouping: "Customers"
    },
    {
      id: "b1",
      name: "Create Booking",
      grouping: "Booking"
    },
    {
      id: "b2",
      name: "Update Booking",
      grouping: "Booking"
    },
    {
      id: "b3",
      name: "Remove Booking",
      grouping: "Booking"
    },
    {
      id: "f1",
      name: "View Invoices",
      grouping: "Accounting"
    },
    {
      id: "f2",
      name: "Create Invoice",
      grouping: "Accounting"
    },
    {
      id: "f3",
      name: "Update Invoice",
      grouping: "Accounting"
    },
    {
      id: "f4",
      name: "Pay Invoice",
      grouping: "Acounting"
    },
    {
      id: "f5",
      name: "Update Customer Status",
      grouping: "Accounting"
    }
  ],

  roles: [{
      name: "Admin",
      rolePermissions: ["u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5", "r1", "r2", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "m1", "m2", "c1", "c2", "c3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"]
    },
    {
      name: "Sales",
      rolePermissions: ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "c1", "c2", "c3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "m1"]
    },
    {
      name: "Maintenance",
      rolePermissions: ["a1", "a5", "m1", "m2"]
    },
    {
      name: "Accounting",
      rolePermissions: ["c1", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining ittus's suggestion regarding b-form-checkbox-group with several attempts and re-reads of the bootstrap-vue docs I come up with the following:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      permissions: [{
          id: "a1",
          name: "View Assets"
        },
        {
          id: "a2",
          name: "Add Asset"
        },
        {
          id: "a3",
          name: "Modifiy Assets"
        }
      ],

      roles: [{
          name: "Admin",
          permissions: ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
        },
        {
          name: "Sales",
          permissions: ["a1"]
        },
        {
          name: "Maintenance",
          permissions: ["a1"]
        },
        {
          name: "Accounting",
          permissions: ["a1"]
        },
      ]
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.headerRow {
  padding: .75rem;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dee2e6;
}

.bodyRow {
  padding: .75rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-container>
          <div id='permissionsTable'>
            <b-row class='headerRow'>
              <b-col cols='3'>Permissions</b-col>
              <b-col v-for="role in roles" v-bind:key="role.name">{{role.name}}</b-col>
            </b-row>
            <b-row v-for="permission in permissions" v-bind:key="permission.name" class="bodyRow">
              <b-col cols='3'>{{permission.name}}</b-col>
              <b-col v-for="(role, index) in roles" v-bind:key="role.name">
                <b-form-checkbox-group v-bind:id="role.name" v-bind:name="role.name + 'Permissions'" v-model="roles[index].permissions" >  
                  <b-form-checkbox v-bind:value="permission.id"/>
                </b-form-checkbox-group>
              </b-col>
          </b-row>
         </div>
        </b-container>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Explanation ?**

As both ittus and the bootstrap docs specify, we must wrap `<b-form-checkbox>` in a `<b-form-checkbox-group>` and then use `v-model` to link the group with an array.  After playing around with it for a little while (about 10 hrs), I finally got it through my skull that I just needed to then bind the `value` attribute of the `<b-form-checkbox>` to the `permission.id` variable obtained from the `v-for` in the row definition above.

**I'd love any additional comments on *why or how* this works.  I guess I'm surprised that the `<b-form-checkbox>` has visibility to variables from outside the `<b-form-checkbox-group>`**

Here is a quote of the relevant bootstrap-vue documentation found [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-checkbox)

> **Value(s)**
>
> By default,  value will be true when checked and
> false when unchecked. You can customize the checked and
> unchecked values by specifying the value and unchecked-value
> properties.
>
> v-model binds to the checked property. When you have multiple
> checkboxes that bind to a single data state variable, you must provide
> an array reference [] to your v-model!
>
> Note that when v-model is bound to multiple checkboxes (i.e an array
> ref), the unchecked-value is not used. Only the value(s) of the
> checked chcekboxes will be returned in the v-model bound array. You
> should provide unique values for each checkbox's value prop.
>
> **Multiple checkboxes and accessibility**
>
> When binding multiple checkboxes together, you should set the name prop to the
> same value for all s in the group individually or via the name  > prop of . This will inform users of assitive
> technologies that the checkboxes are related.
>
> Whenever using multple checkboxes, it is recommended that the
>  be placed in a  component to
> associate a label with the entire group of checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `b-form-checkbox-group` to bind v-model as an array. I'm not sure how to do it inside v-table, but there is a workaround with `methods`

```
<b-form-checkbox id="admin" v-model="adminRolePermissions" 
  @input="onInputAdminRoles($event, row.item.id)"
  :checked="adminRolePermissions.includes(row.item.id)" value="row.item.id"/>
```

and defined custom method:

```
 methods: {
    onInputAdminRoles (isCheck, roleId) {
      if (isCheck) {
        this.adminRolePermissions = this.adminRolePermissions.concat([roleId])
      } else {
        this.adminRolePermissions = this.adminRolePermissions.filter (item => item !== roleId)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work, but thanks for offering the help. The workaround results in the same behavior. Also, you need a :stop after the @input so as to stop the infinite loop which occurs otherwise...

Comment: I ended up building off the first sentence in your answer.  I'm going to provide my own answer below to demonstrate the result.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a key on your checkboxes.

```
<b-table responsive :items="items" :fields="fields" head-variant="dark">
  <template slot="admin" slot-scope="row">
    <b-form-checkbox id="admin" :key="row.index" v-model="adminRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
    <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="adminRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/>               -->
  </template>
  <template slot="sales" slot-scope="row">
    <b-form-checkbox id="sales" :key="row.index" v-model="salesRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
    <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="salesRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/>               -->
  </template>
  <template slot="maint" slot-scope="row">
    <b-form-checkbox id="maint" :key="row.index" v-model="maintRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>
    <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="salesRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/> -->              
  </template>            
  <template slot="account" slot-scope="row">
    <b-form-checkbox id="accou" :key="row.index" v-model="accouRolePermissions" value="row.item.id"/>              
    <!-- <b-form-checkbox v-model="accouRolePermissions" v-bind:id="row.item.id"/> -->
  </template>
</b-table>
```